# How to redirect in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Basically i have explored how we can use get and post in api's using ionic2.

But i have been stucked seriously on how to go to welcome screen after authentication.

This is my html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
    <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username">

    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password"><br><br><br>

    <button round block (click)="submit()">Submit</button>

  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your ts file

import your welcome screen class and write the below function

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){}

submit(){
  this.navCtrl.push(WelcomeScreen,{});
}
```

you can use push pop and setRoot depending upon your need to know more about navigation in ionic please refer this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController.

Comment: Hi Mohan : on using so it gives error :                    error_handler.js:50 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for NavController!       . In console

Comment: ofcourse you have to import your welcome page and login page in `app.module.ts` file and add it to your `entryCompopnent` and `declaration`

Comment: Basically  i am having a fresh ionic2 including menus : In that i included import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';      and  the time i am passing it in constructor as constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl:NavController)    it   is giving me error   No provider for NavController!

Comment: you can go to app folder and inside that you will find app.module.ts file

Comment: thanks a lot .. in need of your valuable suggestion that i am using ionic including sidemenus.. in this how can set that on successfull login only user can see welcome screen which includes that menus

Comment: I mean should i create a new component which will be my default one as i am having app.component.ts as a default one and one successfull login should redirect to menu page